# Is there any PHP code that does not work on IIS?

Tags: php, iis

My apologies if this is a duplicate post post but after some searching, I did not find what I am looking for.

Is there any PHP code (syntax) that does not work on IIS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the PHP *syntax* is exactly the same on every platform, even outside web servers.

Of course there might be some small differences in platform-specific code and variables. A good example is PHP's [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal which isn't fully populated on IIS

Answer (score 1):

If standard PHP, and PHP module is installed, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

PCNTL won't work in a windows enviroment.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

Consider also the warning here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php
if you want to use file function to read from a url.
Despite it is a not very possible case, I have faced it.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
>    A good example is PHP's $_SERVER superglobal which isn't fully populated on IIS

You can fix this with something like this

```
function setRequestURI() {
    //Sets $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for IIS
    if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || !$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
        if (!($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = @$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))  {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        }
        if (isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP is not depends on Operating system. You can equally run your PHP script on any platform , with proper modules installed on web server needed for php script to run.